# Вернуть свою ошибку

Tags: sql, postgresql

Можно ли создать свою ошибку в sql, в частности на postgre и вернуть ее по запросу

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существует оператор [RAISE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Comment: А вызов я смотрю делают через функцию, нельзя сразу в запросе ее вызвать? `select raise notice 'blabla';`

Comment: SELECT-то зачем? вот так сразу и пиши: `RAISE NOTICE 'blabla';` - авось получится...

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RAISE"
LINE 1: RAISE NOTICE 'blabla';

Comment: тоже ошибонька - 
`select 
case when 1=1 then
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'k;sdjk;lsajdhf;kljasdh'
end
`
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"
LINE 3:     RAISE EXCEPTION 'k;sdjk;lsajdhf;kljasdh'

Comment: Ну видать не предназначен RAISE для такого использования...

Comment: Ну а что можно тогда привернуть? Чтобы получить ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

Попробуйте использовать `RAISE EXCEPTION`, как это указано в документации, а не так, как Вы приводите:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Nonexistent ID --> %', user_id
      USING HINT = 'Please check your user ID';
```